# Spell check in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

Is there a good way to do spell check using SSIS?

I have a table with `nvarchar(max)` column. I need to check this column for spelling errors. Perfect result would be:

> "No spelling errors found"

or

> "Have x spelling errors" + list of misspelled words

Also there should be possibility to add words to valid word list..

Comment: @Murtaza for now just looking for possibilities. Have seen there is web services that does that (but high costs). Also seen solutions like this (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/376607/Spell-Checker-Web-Service-Using-a-WPF-TextBox), but guess not very robust one :).

Comment: @Murtaza most possible there will be need for web service.

Comment: The possible thing you can do is use .NET C# and Windows Word Library for Spell check. you will need to script in SSIS package to ready the value and send the appropriate output as Alert or in execution log. Check this link - http://www.nullskull.com/q/10054122/is-there-any-spell-check-libray-in-dotnet.aspx